# XDocument or XmlDocument to JSON with C#

Tags: c#, xml, json, linq-to-xml, json.net

I have this XML which is great:

```
<Products>
  <Product ProductCode="C1010" CategoryName="Coins" />
  <Product ProductCode="C1012" CategoryName="Coins" />
  <Product ProductCode="C1013" CategoryName="Coins" />
</Products>
```

but it outputs to this JSON:

```
{"Products":{"Product":[{"@ProductCode":"C1010","@CategoryName":"Coins"},
                        {"@ProductCode":"C1012","@CategoryName":"Coins"},     
                        {"@ProductCode":"C1013","@CategoryName":"Coins"}]}}
```

I would like no 'Product' sublevel in my json because all three lines are a product. This is my C# code:

```
//x is an XDocument. 
JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(x, Formatting.None, false)
//JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(x); //I also tried without the formatting and the boolean.
```

When I 'convert' an XDocument to XmlDocument and use:

```
var xmlDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
using (var xmlReader = x.CreateReader())
{
    xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
}
JsonConvert.SerializeXmNode(xmlDocument);
```

It gives me exactly the same output. So how can I modify my JSON parsing such that I have a simple list of products. I prefer the cleanest solution.

To be perhaps a bit more clear, I'd something like this as output:

```
[{"@ProductCode":"C1010","@CategoryName":"Coins"},
{"@ProductCode":"C1012","@CategoryName":"Coins"},     
{"@ProductCode":"C1013","@CategoryName":"Coins"}]
```

Comment: As you might be aware, that `JSON`-output represents that `XML`-input. To change it you are "breaking" it.

Comment: Have you tried calling `JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(x, Formatting.None, true)`? that should omit the root node.

Comment: Lol, flipping the bool was exactly what I needed! thanks @Jehof

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the method call

```
JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(x, Formatting.None, true);
```

this will omit the root node and should create what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Instread of using xml writer or con version Just read from the original xml file an write in a new file  use file stream writer.

basically you would be:

```
List xml_retrevedData = new List();
FileStramWriter fr = new FileStramWriter(); 
fr.Write("{"Products":[{"@ProductCode":" //colection item 
variable1.data1","@CategoryName":"//colection item 
variable1.data2"}, {"@ProductCode":"//colection item 
variable2.data1","@CategoryName":"//colection item 
variable11.data1"},
{"@ProductCode":"//colection item variable13.data1","@CategoryName":"//colection item variable13.data3"}]}"); 
// in side the file stream Writer
```

Comment: uhh I want a json file and I don't understand how you plan to get xml to json, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: parse the xml file through LinQ and stre it i a collection or you could directly write  in the jason file format .   the best way to do so is by creating a file in isolated storage through isolated file stream and name the file filename.jason .. then you could write in the file usin file write  ..but dont  forget  to customize it to jason format ...

Comment: basically you would be" {"Products":[{"@ProductCode":"//colection item variable 1.data1","@CategoryName":"//colection item variable 1.data2"},
                        {"@ProductCode":"//colection item variable 2.data1","@CategoryName":"//colection item variable11.data1"},     
                        {"@ProductCode":"//colection item variable13.data1","@CategoryName":"//colection item variable13.data3"}]}  " in side the file stream Writer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public string getData(ref XmlDocument doc) {

        JObject productobj = new JObject();

        var productsenum = from p in doc.GetElementsByTagName("product").Cast<XmlElement>()
                           select p;

        JArray products = new JArray();
        foreach (XmlElement p in productsenum) {
            JObject pobj = new JObject();
            pobj["ProductCode"] = p.GetAttribute("ProductCode");
            pobj["CategoryName"]= p.GetAttribute("CategoryName");

            products.Add(pobj);
        }

        JObject product = new JObject();
        product["Product"] = products;

        productobj["Products"] = product;

        return productobj.ToString();
    }
```